# How to make a word triangle with spaces where next characters will appear

Tags: java

I'm having trouble creating spaces before my string.
i want it to look like this

```
     a
    na
   ana
  nana
 anana
Banana
```

here is my code now

```
    public static void main(String[] args){
    String str = "Banana";
    for(int y = str.length() - 1; y >=  0 ; y--) {
        System.out.println(str.substring(y));
    }
}

a
na
ana
nana
anana
Banana
```

I just need the characters shifted to the right as many characters as the string.

Comment: I should add that this is for any String. not just Banana.

Answer (score 1):

```
System.out.format("%"+str.length()+"s%n", str.substring(y));
```

Definitely better if you store the length first, as suggested in comment

```
String str = "Banana";
String formatString = "%"+str.length()+"s%n";
for(int y = str.length() - 1; y >=  0 ; y--) {
    System.out.format(formatString , str.substring(y));
}
```

Comment: You should store the format string into a variable, instead of computing it each time in the loop.  :-)